# SSD Compatibility MacBook Pro 2010 (6,2)

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, macbook, macbook-pro

I just rebuilt this laptop (battery and HDD failure) and I went with a 1TB Samsung 850 Evo. I want to dual boot Ubuntu on it and ideally, I would like Ubuntu to really be my main operating system.

I found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro6-2/Precise) that seems to show that it doesn't like SSDs but then there's a section that talks about doing it anyways. Just want to see what the best way to do it is, if it's really even possible. I ask because the write up is quite dated and wasn't sure if maybe things have changed to make it easier to use SSDs or not?

Thanks in advance, and here are the system specs just in case.

```
2.66 GHz i7
4GB RAM (have 8GB on the way)
GeForce GT 330M 512 MB
```

Comment: Welcome to AU! The easiest way to find out, would be to [create a bootable DVD/USB with Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/), boot your computer from it, select "Try Ubuntu" to run Ubuntu without modifying your computer and test the device support. Even in the case of failure, this would have the advantage, that you can ask a question with a concrete issue, which would be on topic on AU unlike your current question. The DVD/USB can later double as installation medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the bug report linked to from the guide](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mactel-support/+bug/817017) this appears to be fixable either by setting AHCI mode, or using EFI. I've only played with even older Macs, but back in those days I used rEFIt to set up an easy dual-boot; these days the working fork of rEFIt is [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind). In the bug report folks mention just using grub-efi, which is another option for you once Ubuntu is already installed, although something like rEFInd might make it easier to perform the installation in EFI mode in the first place, since it should be able to boot the USB or DVD you use for installation in EFI mode from the GUI boot menu.

The main caveat seems to be that the proprietary NVIDIA driver won't work if you boot via EFI. I don't know if that's still true, after all most of the comments in that bug report are from a few years ago, but you might find the default nouveau open-source driver will work just fine (honestly, in my experience it's often more stable, it just doesn't necessarily perform as well; chances are you aren't playing demanding 3D games on a 2010 Macbook anyways, however!).

Comment: ya. no 3d stuff, I've got a gaming rig built for that type stuff :) this is just to learn Linux even more by immersing myself. so as long as I use rEFInd then I shouldn't really have an issue? Then it's just a matter of going through the guide and getting things running?

Comment: From what I've read that seems to be true. You can install rEFInd in OSX which will give you a GUI boot menu, and then from there you can install Ubuntu (or Kubuntu or whatnot) by selecting a bootable DVD or USB stick, and things _should_ all be fine.